# aws_sdk: how can I identify if my device is connected to the aws server

Tags: c, aws-sdk, esp32

I have a device (esp32s2) which is IoT enabled and communicating with AWS server.

The device is connecting to the internet via router. I want to check from the device, if the router is connected to the internet or not. If not connected, I need to disconnect mqtt broker instantly.

I know there is aws_iot_yield happening, but it is taking too much of time to change the client state (~5-10 mins) after disconnection. So, is there is any other way in which I can come to know if the device is connected to the mqtt broker or not using AWS sdk?

I want to avoid using pinging to some address/server as it will increase the usage of resources.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the connectivity to the AWS server trough internet depends on the network elements, the only reliable way to know if you are connected to internet is to send a package to a know address and receive the response. Simplest way to do this is to use ICMP (ping) protocol. Usually the most reliable destination to ping is the Google DNS server 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 which is a cluster service and it's always replying on the ping.

You can control the pause between two pings and how many pings you will send in one session in order to preserve the resources.

Alternative approach is to use a router that can send messages to a monitoring device that the link state was changed (by example SNMP trap). But this is not fully reliable method since the router can not detect all scenarios where the connectivity to your AWS server is lost.

Comment: Seems like that is only the best option we have. Anyhow, we have used AWS SDK ping intervals to achieve this task, thanks for the reply!